# php contact form error and success message missing

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I'm having problems with generating the success or error message after sending PHP form. The email arrives correctly but the blank scree afterwards is a problem.

```
 <?php
        if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $puhelin = $_POST['puhelin'];
            $ajankohta = $_POST['ajankohta'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];
            $human = intval($_POST['human']);
            $from = 'x.fi';
            $to = 'aleksanteri.heliovaara@x.com';
            $subject = 'x ';

            $body ="Nimi: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Viesti:\n $message\n Ajankohta:\n $ajankohta\n Puhelin:\n $puhelin";

            if (!$_POST['name']) {
                $errName = 'Annan nimesi';
            }
                if (!$_POST['ajankohta']) {
                $errName = 'Anna ajankohta';
            }

            if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $errEmail = 'Ole hyvä ja anna oikea osoite';
            }
            if (!$_POST['puhelin']) {
                $errName = 'Anna puhelinnumero';
            }

            if (!$_POST['message']) {
                $errMessage = 'Kirjoita viesti';
            }
            if ($human !== 5) {
                $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
            }
```

It seems to me that there is a problem with this if.

```
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
            $result='Success';
        } else {
            $result='Fail';
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Here is the form markup:

```
  <div class="contact-form">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
              <h2 class="page-header text-center">Yhteyslomake</h2>
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="index.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nimesi</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nimesi" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="esimerkki@esimerkki.fi" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="puhelin" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Puhelin</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="" class="form-control" id="puhelin" name="puhelin" placeholder="+358" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Viesti</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message" placeholder="Kerro juhliesi sijainti ja pieni kuvaus"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="ajankohta" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ajankohta</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="" class="form-control" id="ajankohta" name="ajankohta" placeholder="Päivä / Kuukausi / Kellonaika" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="human" class="col-sm-2 control-label">2 + 3 = ?</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="Vastauksesi">
                        <p class='text-danger'></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Lähetä" class="btn btn-primary">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Turn on error_reporting first

Comment: Are you echoing the `$result`, or just assigning it? It's not going to output anything if you don't tell it to.

Comment: Share the form markup.

Comment: @aynber I was thinking that the php would render the text: "success" or "fail" without assigning to another .html etc.

Comment: You don't need to load another html file. Just echo out the variable. PHP only renders what you tell it to.

Answer (score 1):

```
Assign all error message in single variable 

Ex: $error = array();
if($name == '') {
$error[name] = 'Name is invalid';
}

if($email == '') {
$error[email] = 'Email is invalid';
}

$cErrors = count($errors);

if ($cErrors > 0) {
  echo '<p>Total errors: ' . $cErrors . '</p>';
  $error = '<p>ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!</p>';
  echo "<ul>";
  echo implode("\n", $error);
  echo "</ul>";
}
```